# SQL Variable in Where Clause

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

```
Dim varCity As String
varCity = Me.txtDestinationCity
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState FROM [TDestinationType] WHERE" & Me.txtDestinationCity & "= [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity]"
```

I am trying to select the states for the selected city. There is a drop down box with a list of cities. That box is titled `txtDestinationCity`.

It says I have an error in my FROM clause.

Thank you

Comment: If `Me.txtDestinationCity` is a string to test a column value against, you need to quote it

Answer (score 1):

You miss a space and some quotes. How about:

```
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState FROM [TDestinationType] WHERE '" & Me.txtDestinationCity & "' = [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity]"
```

Copy that next to your original to see the difference.

And for reasons SQL, PLEASE reverse the comparison. Always mention the column left and the value right:

```
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState FROM [TDestinationType] WHERE [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity] = '" & Me.txtDestinationCity & "'"
```

Since the quotes are annoying and easy to miss, i suggest defining a function like this:

```
Public Function q(ByVal s As String) As String
    q = "'" & s & "'"
End Function
```

and then write the SQL string like that:

```
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState FROM [TDestinationType] WHERE [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity] = " & q(Me.txtDestinationCity)
```

This makes sure you ALWAYS get both quotes at the right places and not get confused by double-single-double quote sequences.

If you care about SQL-injection (yes, look that up), please use the minimum

```
Public Function escapeSQL(sql As String) As String
    escapeSQL = Replace(sql, "'", "''")
End Function
```

and use it in all places where you concatenate user-input to SQL-clauses, like this:

```
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState FROM [TDestinationType] WHERE [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity] = " & q(escapeSQL(Me.txtDestinationCity))
```

Lastly, breakt it for readability. I doubt your editor shows 200 characters wide:

```
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = _
    "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState " & _
    "FROM [TDestinationType] " & _
    "WHERE [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity] = " & q(escapeSQL(Me.txtDestinationCity))
```

Note the trailing spaces in each line! Without them, the concatenation will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easier to troubleshoot your query construction if you set it to a variable (e.g., strSQL) first.  Then you can put a breakpoint and see it right before it executes.

Answer (score -1):

You need a space after WHERE. Change `WHERE"` to `WHERE<space>"`

```
Me.txtDestinationState.RowSource = "SELECT tPreTravelDestinationState FROM [TDestinationType] WHERE " & Me.txtDestinationCity & "= [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity]"
```

Comment: it is now asking me to enter parameter values for both the city i select and [TDestinationType].[tPreTravelDestinationCity]

Comment: you need to put quotes around your string but @Oliver already answered this